# what are the address fields in wlan frame format?

Tags: networking, tcp, wifi

If an AP (Access Point) is connected by Ethernet via a switch. And a station (STA1) is also connected to the same switch. 
    Now another station (STA2) is connected to the Access point wireless interface.
    If i try to ping from station1 (STA2) to station2 (STA1) how address fields in the 802.11 MAC frame change?

Answer (score 1):

Packet flows from STA2 to AP on air, from AP to STA1 on ether-net via the switch. When packet leaves STA2 to AP it will have TA = SA = MAC of STA2. RA = BSSID of AP and DA = broadcast MAC address (because STA2 only know IP of STA1, not MAC address). For a detailed explanation you can refer to [this](https://sharkfest.wireshark.org/sharkfest.08/T1-5_Bardwell_Intro%20to%20WLAN%20Analysis.pdf) link. Read under the heading **802.11 and Ethernet Addressing** on page 12.